# R fast method to find closest value in vector B for each element in A

Tags: r

I have a very large unsorted vector A and a sorted vector B (relatively short).

```
A = runif(n = 1e6)
B = seq(0,1,by = 1e-3)
```

Now given a direction 'forward' or 'backward', for each element in A, find the nearest element in B with that direction. Eg for 'forward'

```
A2 = sapply(A, function(x) B[B>=x][1])
```

gives the result. However, this is too slow as `sapply` loops over A.

```
> system.time(sapply(A, function(x) B[B>=x][1]))
   user  system elapsed 
  17.93    0.00   17.93
```

Is there a way to do this much faster?

(It is guaranteed that `min(B)<min(A)` and `max(B)>max(A)`, if this is useful)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `findInterval` function solves this exact problem using binary search. Try this:

```
B[findInterval(A,B)+1]
```

A comparison:

```
set.seed(44)
A <- runif(n = 1e6)
B <- seq(0,1,by = 1e-3)
system.time(A2<-sapply(A, function(x) B[B>=x][1]))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 18.058   0.000  15.606
system.time(A3<-B[findInterval(A,B)+1])  
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.00    0.00    0.07
identical(A2,A3)
#[1] TRUE
```